# What's the difference between .sendKeys and .sendText in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have a java selenium3 project in which my developers have used `.sendText` instead of `.sendKeys` to enter a string in a form field which is referenced by a page object. I would have used `.sendKeys` myself, so what is the difference? (Yes, I googled)

Comment: There is no such method `sendText` in the selenium API. Can you please provide more information - especially more code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `sendText`method present in **selenium**.

Although your team mates have used it. It will probably be a wrapper of `sendKeys()`method.

**Suggestion** :

Install **decompiler** in your IDE and check the internals of `sendText` method.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're using Eclipse (I don't know if this works the same way in other IDE's like intelliJ) just control-click the `.sendText` code and it should take you directly to the sendText method of the page object itself.  I think you'll find as suggested above, that it's only a wrapper and it uses `.sendKeys` ultimately.